# Can't choose .NET 4.7

Tags: visual-studio-2017, .net-4.7

I am trying to start a new project using .NET 4.7.  I have Creators Update installed as well as the latest version of Visual Studio 2017.  When I start a project and device to choose a .NET version, the latest .NET framework version I have is 4.6.2.  When I go to download a new .NET framework, it only lists 4.6.2 as the latest via MS that you can download.  It says that .NET 4.7 is included in VS 2017.  What am I missing?

Comment: Have you updated Visual Studio 2017 for .NET Framework 4.7?

Comment: It was in the Components section of the Visual Studio Installer and I didn't realize it.  When I installed 2017 I chose all components and when the updates came out I just updated it without clicking the components tab to see if new components were also there.  Lesson learned.

Comment: I am not finding in the installer components to choose .NET 4.7 when I am trying to install the updated VS 2017 in Windows Server 2016 OS. Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: @RinoTom I'm not sure.. I didn't try until after I upgraded to Windows 10 Creators Update.  It says it's included in VS2017 so I would assume it would be there but you may need Creators Update also.  Hopefully someone else can chime in to verify.  In the installer, at the top, there are 3 categories, Workloads, Individual Components, and Language Packs.  For me it was in the Individual Components under .NET as .NET Framework 4.7 SDK and .NET Framework 4.7 targeting pack. Also, make sure VS2017 is completely updated possibly.  Hope this helps.

Comment: @MichaelPuckettII, I tried the installation on Windows Server 2016 which doesn't have Creator's Update OR as I can understabd on a further research (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb822049(v=vs.110).aspx), even .NET 4.7 is not released for Windows Server 2016 yet it looks like. So that might be the reason I am not finding .NET 4.7 in the VS 2017 installation i tried.

Comment: @RinoTom  That sounds accurate then.  This may be something you'll have to wait for when server is updated to CU.  I'm speculating though and don't know for sure but it seems like you've nailed down the issue.

Answer (score 165, accepted):

You need to go to Visual Studio Installer and install an optional component ".NET Framework 4.7 Development Tools".

Comment: Wow... I have searched for hours and it was right in front of me.  :/ Thanks man.  I'll mark as answered as soon as it lets me.  Installing it now.

Comment: @GWigWam I don't either, but as 4.7 is initially only available in Win10's "Creator's Update", I'm assuming that is a dependency.

Comment: My VS installer doesn't have .NET 4.7 in the list of .NET components. What am I missing? https://www.screencast.com/t/f78eR5cUk

Comment: @DmitriNesteruk The .NET 4.7 Framework itself should be installed.  Currently it is only possible by having Win 10 CU.

Comment: @dvom my system is win10, yet cannot see 4.7 either in installer

Comment: @Elaine  Do you also have the Creators Update installed?

Comment: To install after installing VS already, I closed VS2017, started the "Visual Studio Installer" program, clicked "Modify" under the installation I wanted to change, expanded ".NET desktop development" on the right hand side (since I already had this workload installed), and checked ".NET 4.7 desktop 4.7 development tools". I then clicked "Modify" in the bottom right to make the change

Comment: Visual Studio 2017 setup lets you choose .NET 4.6.2 and .NET 4.7 depending on your installed OS. in catalog.json file you can find 4.6.2 "supportedOS":"10.0.14393" and 4.7 "supportedOS":"10.0.15058".

Comment: [.NET version 4.6.2 and 4.7 option missing from Visual Studio](http://irisclasson.com/2017/09/21/net-version-4-6-2-and-4-7-option-missing-from-visual-studio/) post by [Iris Classon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/984153/iris-classon) demonstrates where to find these options in VS installer.

Comment: The name of the component in VS 2017 to install was ".Net Framework 4.7.2 targetting pack" for me.

Comment: The installer lists .NET Framework 4.6.2 development tools as unchecked but 4.6.2 is already available for projects in Visual Studio. Why is 4.6.2 available but not 4.7, 4.7.1, or 4.7.2 when all are unchecked in the installer?

Comment: For those saying the installer didn't give the option to modify their installation, make sure you're using the installer located here: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer

Comment: Those that can't find the installer, just go to "Help" then "Check for Updates", once it's checked for updates, on the right hand side is "Open Visual Studio Installer", you can then modify it (it's on the down arrow on 'More')

Comment: MOre info, not good solutions https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/61785/net-framework-47-not-listed-as-a-target-framework.html

Comment: You may have to go to "Individual Components" and manually select the SDK of the version you want.

Answer (score 18):

"A picture is worth a thousand bytes (with adequate compression)" and all that jazz...

[image]

Comment: In the installer of Visual Studio 2019, .NET Framework 4.7.2 development tools is not in the "Optional"-list, but under "Included".

Comment: You may have to go to "Individual Components" and manually select the SDK of the version you want.

Answer (score 11):

The .NET Framework 4.7 was released as part of Windows 10 Creators. For other versions of Windows, you have to install the .NET Framework 4.7.

[Offline Installer of .NET Framework 4.7 Developer pack](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=55168)

Comment: Just a note that even this stand-alone installer will **not** work on Windows 10 Enterprise N 2015 LTSB. It gives a [not supported error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EwX7z.png).

Answer (score 10):

So I could not find the  .Net Framework 4.7.2 Developer tool even in Visual Studio Installer. However you can download & run them from here:

https://www.microsoft.com/net/download/visual-studio-sdks

Comment: You may have to go to "Individual Components" and manually select the SDK of the version you want.

Answer (score 4):

For anyone late to the party here; In Visual Studio 2019, I had this problem by using a .Net Core template to create my project.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/visual-studio-multi-targeting-overview?view=vs-2019

> For non-.NET Framework project templates, for example .NET Core templates, the Framework drop-down list doesn't appear.

Make sure you pick a .Net Framework template when creating a project/solution :)

Comment: I feel so stupid now.  I just discovered this on my own but wish I'd have scrolled down to this sooner, instead of only when checking to see if someone else had posted the solution I found.  New laptop with bare minimum options installed threw me off.