# Visual Studio 2017: can't see target framework 4.7

Tags: visual-studio-2017, .net-4.7

From [.NET blog](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2017/04/05/announcing-the-net-framework-4-7/) I came to know that, they have added support for targeting .NET framework 4.7 in **Visual Studio 17**. I just have installed Visual Studio 2017 but not getting the target framework 4.7. Highest target framework i can see is **4.6.1**.

Comment: Do you really need that framework which is 4.7

Comment: yes. I wanna start a project with using 4.7.

Answer (score 8):

Start the Visual Studio Installer and install the .NET Framework 4.7 Development Tools.

Comment: I see 4.6.2 Development Tools but no 4.7. It looks like the framework is on my machine, though. And it's supposed to come with 2017 anyway.

Comment: Same for me, I don't see the Development Tools 4.7 although I have the framework 4.7 installed and VS is up to date. From https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43316307/cant-choose-net-4-7 it looks like the Windows 10 Creators Update must be installed to see it.

Comment: You can find it under Azure Development.