# .Net Framework 4.8 not showing up in Visual Studio Target Framework dropdown

Tags: .net, visual-studio, .net-framework-version

I have installed .Net Framework 4.8 and confirmed the same in the registry entry.

[image]

I am still not able to see the same in Target Framework dropdown in project properties tab.

Comment: Have you installed the *SDK* though? That shows what runtime is installed. Which Visual Studio version are you using? If it's Visual Studio 2017 and later, start Visual Studio Installer and ensure `.NET Framework 4.8` support is checked either in `Individual Items` or in the payload section you want

Comment: I have installed the developers pack which has both SDK and the pack. Ref: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58000913/2858235

Comment: SO questions aren't references, they are questions that may or may not have anything to do with your own question. What Visual Studio version have you installed? That answer says what I also said though - use Visual Studio Installer

Comment: BTW that answer also says `use the Installer`

Comment: I have used the installer only and the registry entry confirms the same I guess. I am on VS 2017

Answer (score 13):

Microsoft have made it very confusing with the different Project templates to create any 2.0 to 4.8 .Net Framework projects

The following template sounds plausible:

[image: Plausible Template for Net Framework]

Note how there are only two options.

[image: Net Core only options]

The correct templates to look at :
[image]

Contain "(.Net Framework)" within the title:

[image: Windows Forms Project Template .Net Framework 2.0 to 4.8]

Comment: Thanks for the "(.Net Framework)" hint, Peter! +1 for that.

Comment: Awesome, Thanks bro. i reinstall too many times until see ur comment

Comment: I owe you a beer bro!

Comment: You saved me a lot of time!