# (EasyHook) DLL not recognized from within same project

Tags: c#, dll, visual-studio-2019, easyhook

Apologies if this is a stupid question; I'm not overly familiar with Visual Studio and definitely not the new version.

I am trying to hook calls to TextOutA from a Windows application using EasyHook, roughly [following this tutorial](http://easyhook.github.io/tutorials/remotefilemonitor.html), in Visual Studio 2019. (I am 100% certain that they are TextOutA; decompiler output indicates as much, and I was able to successfully hook them using C++. Unfortunately C# is far more supported/documented than C++ for EasyHook.)

Per the tutorial I have a console application and a class library as two projects in the same solution. Getting the Visual Studio solution to compile at all was somewhat bumpy -- I had to manually edit the .csproj files to .NET Framework 4.8 (per [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58000123/visual-studio-cant-target-net-framework-4-8)) and it took some tinkering to get it working. But now I am worried that I have tinkered too much.

What happens: The code compiles without errors and warnings, and seemingly runs successfully. However, nothing in the DLL seems to be called; none of its code appears to be executed, a breakpoint in Run() is never hit, and it still compiles if I just get rid of the Run() code entirely.

This is the console app code, so far (filenames redacted; there may well be other issues with this code but I'd have to run it to find out):

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string injectionLibrary = Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location), "[name of DLL].dll");

            Console.WriteLine(injectionLibrary);

            try
            {
                Int32 processID = 0;
                Process[] process = Process.GetProcessesByName("[process name]");
                Console.Write(process[0]);
                processID = process[0].Id;

                EasyHook.RemoteHooking.Inject(
                        processID,          // ID of process to inject into
                        injectionLibrary,   // 32-bit library to inject (if target is 32-bit)
                        injectionLibrary,   // 64-bit library to inject (if target is 64-bit)
                        null         // the parameters to pass into injected library
                                            // ...
                    );
                Console.WriteLine("Injected, supposedly.");
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
                Console.WriteLine("There was an error while injecting into target: ");
                Console.ResetColor();
                Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
            }

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

And this is the class library:

```
namespace [DLL name]
{
    public class MySimpleEntryPoint : EasyHook.IEntryPoint
    {
        public MySimpleEntryPoint(EasyHook.RemoteHooking.IContext context)
        {
        }
        public void Run(EasyHook.RemoteHooking.IContext context)
        {
            Console.Write("Test");
            var textOutHook = EasyHook.LocalHook.Create(
                EasyHook.LocalHook.GetProcAddress("Gdi32.dll", "TextOutA"),
                new TextOutDelegate(TextOut_Hook),
                this);

            textOutHook.ThreadACL.SetExclusiveACL(new Int32[] { 0 });

        }

        [UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.StdCall,
                CharSet = CharSet.Unicode,
                SetLastError = true)]
        delegate bool TextOutDelegate(IntPtr orig_handle, int x_value, int y_value, string output_string, int color);

        [DllImport("gdi32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, EntryPoint = "TextOutA", SetLastError = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
        static extern bool TextOutA(IntPtr orig_handle, int x_value, int y_value, string lpString, int color);
        bool TextOut_Hook(IntPtr orig_handle, int x_value, int y_value, string output_string, int color)
        {
            // We aren't going to call the original at all... YET
            Console.Write("...intercepted...");
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

The console output for the process is as expected, and so is the output of the path:
C:\Users[my username]\source\repos[name of project]\build\net48\ [name of DLL].dll -- which is indeed where the dll is output to. But, as above, nothing in Run() seems to actually be called, TextOutA certainly isn't being suppressed, etc.

What I have tried:

- Adding both the .dll and the class library project (separately) as references to the console app
- Setting both the .dll and the executable to output to the same folder
- Tweaking the line of code that supposedly gets the path
- Comparing this code to basically any comparable EasyHook projects I can find, nothing seems obviously amiss
- Calling GetProcAddress from within the console app and not the hook; it works as expected, so the problem doesn't seem to be that

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Are you debugging the target you are injecting into? Keep in mind the injected assembly is running within the target not your console app. Probably the main issue is that you have to keep a while loop at the end of Run (while with a sleep) - once you exit that method the assembly will be unloaded - also the hook will be disposed which will uninstall it.

Comment: Thank you for your response! This seems to have solved it (and in retrospect not sure why I didn't try that, could have sworn it was one of the things I did).

Comment: (also I know "color" is incorrect, what I get for coding late at night...)

Answer (score 0):

Answer as per my comment.

There are two things happening in your example:

1. when Run exits your hooks are likely to be cleaned up by the GC and therefore uninstalled
2. when Run exits EasyHook will unload your assembly

The managed EasyHook helper library `EasyLoad` runs your `IEntryPoint.Run` method within a new thread and waits for it to exit. When the method exits the assembly is unloaded etc.

Therefore you should add a while loop at the end of your `Run` method to prevent it exiting until you are finished with your hooks.

```
public void Run(EasyHook.RemoteHooking.IContext context)
{
  // install hooks
  ...

  while (true) {
    Thread.Sleep(500);

    // optionally perform a check to see if should break
  }

  // uninstall hooks / cleanup / etc
}
```