# Visual Studio, Connection lost to the server ERROR

Tags: visual-studio

I have no idea whats going on here. Every time I use a DataGridView and try to use the drop down to add a data source it gives me an error: "Error using the dropdown. The connection to the server has been lost.

[This is what it looks like.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ApKD4.png)

Comment: do you have any server connections listed in visual studio?

Answer (score 2):

Change target .net framework from 5.0 to 4.8  and then create a new project.
[Visual Studio Can't Target .NET Framework 4.8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58000123/visual-studio-cant-target-net-framework-4-8)

Comment: how does this help?

Comment: @DanielA.White because .net (core) winforms support is fairly well bug-laden still, and going back to .net framework is usually a good step if you're writing a winforns app and don't want to bang your head on it for excessive amounts of time