# Project loading error due to missing DefineConstants value, but the values are defined

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2022

I have a .Net-framework 4.8 project which fails to load in Visual Studio 2022 and I simply don't know why.

The error occurs when attempting to open the properties of the project inside Visual Studio.

[image: the-error]

The projects also show an error in the solution explorer, but nothing further is stated:

[image: solution-explorer-view]

I've had an [identical issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75098414/unrelated-loading-error-when-adding-nuget-package-information-to-a-net-framewor/75102545#75102545) with another project, but that was resolved by removing an illegal property.

On my current project, that property is already removed but the error still exists and won't resolve. **I don't understand what is happening under the hood.**

```
System.ArgumentException: Expected 1 values for property Build::DefineConstants, but got 0.
Parameter name: values
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.VS.Implementation.PropertyPages.Designer.Property.Update(ImmutableArray`1 values)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.VS.Implementation.PropertyPages.Designer.Property..ctor(PropertyMetadata metadata, ImmutableArray`1 values, PropertyContext context, ImmutableHashSet`1 varyByDimensions)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.VS.Implementation.PropertyPages.Designer.PropertyContextFactoryBase.ToProperty(IUIProperty property, Page page, Category category, Int32 order, PropertyContext propertyContext, IPropertyEditorRegistry propertyEditorRegistry)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.VS.Implementation.PropertyPages.Designer.ProjectPropertyDataAccess.Observer.<HandleDataAsync>g__CreateProperties|14_5(<>c__DisplayClass14_0& )
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.VS.Implementation.PropertyPages.Designer.ProjectPropertyDataAccess.Observer.<HandleDataAsync>g__ProcessInitialData|14_1(<>c__DisplayClass14_0& )
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.VS.Implementation.PropertyPages.Designer.ProjectPropertyDataAccess.Observer.<InitializeAsync>d__10.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.VS.Implementation.PropertyPages.Designer.ProjectPropertyDataAccess.Observer.<CreateAsync>d__9.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.VS.Implementation.PropertyPages.Designer.ProjectPropertiesEditor.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<<-ctor>b__0>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.VS.Implementation.PropertyPages.Designer.AsyncLoadContent.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<<Initialize>b__0>d.MoveNext()
```

Here is the project file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\Microsoft.Common.props" Condition="Exists('$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\Microsoft.Common.props')" />
  <PropertyGroup>
    <Configuration Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == '' ">Debug</Configuration>
    <Platform Condition=" '$(Platform)' == '' ">AnyCPU</Platform>
    <ProjectGuid>{DA53C3E0-7D05-4BB7-932C-97147BFB0E4C}</ProjectGuid>
    <OutputType>Library</OutputType>
    <AppDesignerFolder>Properties</AppDesignerFolder>
    <RootNamespace>Testcenter.RobotFramework.Exceptions</RootNamespace>
    <AssemblyName>Testcenter.RobotFramework.Exceptions</AssemblyName>
    <TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.8</TargetFrameworkVersion>
    <FileAlignment>512</FileAlignment>
    <DefineConstants>DEBUG</DefineConstants>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|AnyCPU' ">
    <OutputPath>bin\Debug\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>DEBUG;TRACE</DefineConstants>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|AnyCPU' ">
    <OutputPath>bin\Release\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>TRACE</DefineConstants>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Testing|AnyCPU' ">
    <OutputPath>bin\Testing\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>TEST</DefineConstants>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Libraries|AnyCPU' ">
    <OutputPath>bin\Libraries\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>ONLY_LIBRARY</DefineConstants>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup>
    <GeneratePackageOnBuild>true</GeneratePackageOnBuild>
    <PackageId>Testcenter.RobotFramework.Exceptions</PackageId>
    <Version>1.0.0</Version>
    <Authors>Testcenter Team, Some person</Authors>
    <Company>Some company</Company>
    <PackageOutputPath>$(ProjectDir)</PackageOutputPath>
    <Description>A class library providing exception types used in the implementation itself and in keyword libraries.</Description>
    <Title>RobotFramework Remote-Library-Interface for C# (exception types)</Title>
    <Copyright>Copyright (c) Some company 2022</Copyright>
    <RepositoryUrl>https://redacted-url.com/repos/testcenter.robotframework/browse</RepositoryUrl>
    <Product>Testcenter.RobotFramework.Exceptions</Product>
    <AssemblyVersion>1.0.0</AssemblyVersion>
    <FileVersion>1.0.0</FileVersion>
    <!-- Properties which cause problems in Visual Studio. The error doesn't occur if these are commented out.
    More info here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75098414/unrelated-loading-error-when-adding-nuget-package-information-to-a-net-framewor
    <TargetFramework>net48</TargetFramework> -->
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="System" />
    <Reference Include="System.Core" />
    <Reference Include="System.Data" />
    <Reference Include="System.Xml" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Include="Configuration\ConfigurationException.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Configuration\KeywordConfigurationException.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Configuration\ServerConfigurationException.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Keyword\ContinuableKeywordException.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Keyword\FatalKeywordException.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Keyword\KeywordException.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Keyword\NormalKeywordException.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Keyword\KeywordLoadingException.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="NuGet.Build.Tasks.Pack" Version="6.4.0">
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
    </PackageReference>
  </ItemGroup>
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildToolsPath)\Microsoft.CSharp.targets" />
  <!-- To modify your build process, add your task inside one of the targets below and uncomment it. 
         Other similar extension points exist, see Microsoft.Common.targets.
    <Target Name="BeforeBuild">
    </Target>
    <Target Name="AfterBuild">
    </Target>
    -->
</Project>
```

The project fails to load only in Visual Studio, but loads fine in JetBrains Rider.

I have a very similar project file *(seen in the solution explorer)*, which loads just fine and has the exact same property structure and the only difference is the NuGet-Package information and the compiled source files.

Here's also my solution file, which maybe contributes to the problem, but I wouldn't know why or how.

```xml
Microsoft Visual Studio Solution File, Format Version 12.00
# Visual Studio Version 17
VisualStudioVersion = 17.3.32901.215
MinimumVisualStudioVersion = 10.0.40219.1
Project("{FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}") = "Testcenter.RobotFramework", "Testcenter.RobotFramework\Testcenter.RobotFramework.csproj", "{63B8CCEF-5C50-4F25-8E6B-C623DA1BDD2F}"
EndProject
Project("{9A19103F-16F7-4668-BE54-9A1E7A4F7556}") = "Testcenter.RobotFramework.Communication", "Testcenter.RobotFramework.Communication\Testcenter.RobotFramework.Communication.csproj", "{86F3BACB-FC4D-43FC-BA20-659600C6134C}"
EndProject
Project("{9A19103F-16F7-4668-BE54-9A1E7A4F7556}") = "Testcenter.RobotFramework.Exceptions", "Testcenter.RobotFramework.Exceptions\Testcenter.RobotFramework.Exceptions.csproj", "{DA53C3E0-7D05-4BB7-932C-97147BFB0E4C}"
EndProject
Project("{2150E333-8FDC-42A3-9474-1A3956D46DE8}") = "RobotFramework", "RobotFramework", "{1F0EA3DB-C080-432A-9948-DF8461982CDE}"
EndProject
Project("{2150E333-8FDC-42A3-9474-1A3956D46DE8}") = "Testing", "Testing", "{0A74D269-D322-40B9-9193-AC95B08DA488}"
EndProject
Project("{FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}") = "Testcenter.RobotFramework.Test", "testcenter.robotframework.testing\Testcenter.RobotFramework.Test.csproj", "{2079E935-E4C0-460D-A9F1-215E4319C85C}"
EndProject
Project("{2150E333-8FDC-42A3-9474-1A3956D46DE8}") = "RobotLibraries", "RobotLibraries", "{0B0D45E9-0A08-430D-8BF5-219E15465804}"
EndProject
Project("{FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}") = "Testcenter.RobotLibrary.Deditec", "Testcenter.RobotLibrary.Deditec\Testcenter.RobotLibrary.Deditec.csproj", "{C04EA17A-0B86-4180-885D-9EAEC9D5D6DC}"
EndProject
Project("{FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}") = "Testcenter.RobotLibrary.Extension", "Testcenter.RobotLibrary.Extension\Testcenter.RobotLibrary.Extension.csproj", "{6E2D959E-9E66-4402-8E06-1DF0497BC92D}"
EndProject
Project("{2150E333-8FDC-42A3-9474-1A3956D46DE8}") = "CI/CD", "CI/CD", "{F691C5B2-2CF5-445C-A2A1-29F480129B6E}"
    ProjectSection(SolutionItems) = preProject
        dockerfile = dockerfile
        .dockerignore = .dockerignore
        .cicd\hello-world-pipeline.yml = .cicd\hello-world-pipeline.yml
        .cicd\robotframework-release-pipeline.yml = .cicd\robotframework-release-pipeline.yml
        .cicd\scripts\build-solution-or-project.ps1 = .cicd\scripts\build-solution-or-project.ps1
        .cicd\scripts\push-nuget-package.ps1 = .cicd\scripts\push-nuget-package.ps1
        .cicd\tasks\msbuild-project.yml = .cicd\tasks\msbuild-project.yml
        .cicd\tasks\push-nuget.yml = .cicd\tasks\push-nuget.yml
    EndProjectSection
EndProject
Project("{FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}") = "Testcenter.RobotLibrary.HCS.Roombus", "Testcenter.RobotLibrary.HCS.Roombus\Testcenter.RobotLibrary.HCS.Roombus.csproj", "{80A1F57E-39D0-4E33-B8CB-27033FBAEBF4}"
EndProject
Global
    GlobalSection(SolutionConfigurationPlatforms) = preSolution
        Debug|Any CPU = Debug|Any CPU
        Libraries|Any CPU = Libraries|Any CPU
        Release|Any CPU = Release|Any CPU
        Testing|Any CPU = Testing|Any CPU
    EndGlobalSection
    GlobalSection(ProjectConfigurationPlatforms) = postSolution
        {63B8CCEF-5C50-4F25-8E6B-C623DA1BDD2F}.Debug|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Debug|Any CPU
        {63B8CCEF-5C50-4F25-8E6B-C623DA1BDD2F}.Debug|Any CPU.Build.0 = Debug|Any CPU
        {63B8CCEF-5C50-4F25-8E6B-C623DA1BDD2F}.Libraries|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Libraries|Any CPU
        {63B8CCEF-5C50-4F25-8E6B-C623DA1BDD2F}.Release|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Release|Any CPU
        {63B8CCEF-5C50-4F25-8E6B-C623DA1BDD2F}.Release|Any CPU.Build.0 = Release|Any CPU
        {63B8CCEF-5C50-4F25-8E6B-C623DA1BDD2F}.Testing|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Testing|Any CPU
        {86F3BACB-FC4D-43FC-BA20-659600C6134C}.Debug|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Debug|Any CPU
        {86F3BACB-FC4D-43FC-BA20-659600C6134C}.Debug|Any CPU.Build.0 = Debug|Any CPU
        {86F3BACB-FC4D-43FC-BA20-659600C6134C}.Libraries|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Libraries|Any CPU
        {86F3BACB-FC4D-43FC-BA20-659600C6134C}.Release|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Release|Any CPU
        {86F3BACB-FC4D-43FC-BA20-659600C6134C}.Release|Any CPU.Build.0 = Release|Any CPU
        {86F3BACB-FC4D-43FC-BA20-659600C6134C}.Testing|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Testing|Any CPU
        {DA53C3E0-7D05-4BB7-932C-97147BFB0E4C}.Debug|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Debug|Any CPU
        {DA53C3E0-7D05-4BB7-932C-97147BFB0E4C}.Debug|Any CPU.Build.0 = Debug|Any CPU
        {DA53C3E0-7D05-4BB7-932C-97147BFB0E4C}.Libraries|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Libraries|Any CPU
        {DA53C3E0-7D05-4BB7-932C-97147BFB0E4C}.Release|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Release|Any CPU
        {DA53C3E0-7D05-4BB7-932C-97147BFB0E4C}.Release|Any CPU.Build.0 = Release|Any CPU
        {DA53C3E0-7D05-4BB7-932C-97147BFB0E4C}.Testing|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Testing|Any CPU
        {2079E935-E4C0-460D-A9F1-215E4319C85C}.Debug|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Debug|Any CPU
        {2079E935-E4C0-460D-A9F1-215E4319C85C}.Libraries|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Libraries|Any CPU
        {2079E935-E4C0-460D-A9F1-215E4319C85C}.Release|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Release|Any CPU
        {2079E935-E4C0-460D-A9F1-215E4319C85C}.Testing|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Testing|Any CPU
        {2079E935-E4C0-460D-A9F1-215E4319C85C}.Testing|Any CPU.Build.0 = Testing|Any CPU
        {C04EA17A-0B86-4180-885D-9EAEC9D5D6DC}.Debug|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Debug|Any CPU
        {C04EA17A-0B86-4180-885D-9EAEC9D5D6DC}.Libraries|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Libraries|Any CPU
        {C04EA17A-0B86-4180-885D-9EAEC9D5D6DC}.Libraries|Any CPU.Build.0 = Libraries|Any CPU
        {C04EA17A-0B86-4180-885D-9EAEC9D5D6DC}.Release|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Release|Any CPU
        {C04EA17A-0B86-4180-885D-9EAEC9D5D6DC}.Testing|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Testing|Any CPU
        {C04EA17A-0B86-4180-885D-9EAEC9D5D6DC}.Testing|Any CPU.Build.0 = Testing|Any CPU
        {6E2D959E-9E66-4402-8E06-1DF0497BC92D}.Debug|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Debug|Any CPU
        {6E2D959E-9E66-4402-8E06-1DF0497BC92D}.Libraries|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Libraries|Any CPU
        {6E2D959E-9E66-4402-8E06-1DF0497BC92D}.Libraries|Any CPU.Build.0 = Libraries|Any CPU
        {6E2D959E-9E66-4402-8E06-1DF0497BC92D}.Release|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Release|Any CPU
        {6E2D959E-9E66-4402-8E06-1DF0497BC92D}.Testing|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Testing|Any CPU
        {6E2D959E-9E66-4402-8E06-1DF0497BC92D}.Testing|Any CPU.Build.0 = Testing|Any CPU
        {80A1F57E-39D0-4E33-B8CB-27033FBAEBF4}.Debug|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Debug|Any CPU
        {80A1F57E-39D0-4E33-B8CB-27033FBAEBF4}.Libraries|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Libraries|Any CPU
        {80A1F57E-39D0-4E33-B8CB-27033FBAEBF4}.Libraries|Any CPU.Build.0 = Libraries|Any CPU
        {80A1F57E-39D0-4E33-B8CB-27033FBAEBF4}.Release|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Release|Any CPU
        {80A1F57E-39D0-4E33-B8CB-27033FBAEBF4}.Testing|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Testing|Any CPU
        {80A1F57E-39D0-4E33-B8CB-27033FBAEBF4}.Testing|Any CPU.Build.0 = Testing|Any CPU
    EndGlobalSection
    GlobalSection(SolutionProperties) = preSolution
        HideSolutionNode = FALSE
    EndGlobalSection
    GlobalSection(NestedProjects) = preSolution
        {63B8CCEF-5C50-4F25-8E6B-C623DA1BDD2F} = {1F0EA3DB-C080-432A-9948-DF8461982CDE}
        {86F3BACB-FC4D-43FC-BA20-659600C6134C} = {1F0EA3DB-C080-432A-9948-DF8461982CDE}
        {DA53C3E0-7D05-4BB7-932C-97147BFB0E4C} = {1F0EA3DB-C080-432A-9948-DF8461982CDE}
        {2079E935-E4C0-460D-A9F1-215E4319C85C} = {0A74D269-D322-40B9-9193-AC95B08DA488}
        {C04EA17A-0B86-4180-885D-9EAEC9D5D6DC} = {0B0D45E9-0A08-430D-8BF5-219E15465804}
        {6E2D959E-9E66-4402-8E06-1DF0497BC92D} = {0B0D45E9-0A08-430D-8BF5-219E15465804}
        {80A1F57E-39D0-4E33-B8CB-27033FBAEBF4} = {0B0D45E9-0A08-430D-8BF5-219E15465804}
    EndGlobalSection
    GlobalSection(ExtensibilityGlobals) = postSolution
        SolutionGuid = {8B25855F-6BB5-44FA-8793-5F3E05270044}
    EndGlobalSection
EndGlobal
```

Comment: Just happened to me as well

Comment: I AM NOT ALONE! (yay)

Comment: I might have solved it by setting Project ToolsVersion="15.0"

Comment: Did not solve it for me. In the working project the `ToolsVersion` is set to `"4.0"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to give this a definitive answer and also for anyone else stumbling upon this.

The issue was solved together with Microsoft Support:
https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Error-on-opening-project-properties-for-/10416753

The issue came up since in the solution file, there was a wrong Project GUID and Visual Studio attempted to load the project as an SDK-Style project. But in fact they weren't supposed to be SDK-Style projects.

The issue was resolved by manually changing all affected GUIDs to the correct one.

Here is a quote of the problem resolution:

> Looking at the solution file you provided I see the following entries (edited for clarity):

```
Project("{FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}") = "Testcenter.RobotFramework", <project path>, <project ID>
EndProject
Project("{9A19103F-16F7-4668-BE54-9A1E7A4F7556}") = "Testcenter.RobotFramework.Communication", <project path>, <project ID>
EndProject
```

> The first GUID on each line (`“FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC”` and `“9A19103F-16F7-4668-BE54-9A1E7A4F7556”`) tells Visual Studio which component should handle loading the project. Since these are not SDK-style projects I would expect both GUIDs to be `“FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC”`. The `“9A19103F-16F7-4668-BE54-9A1E7A4F7556”` GUID will cause `Testcenter.RobotFramework.Communication.csproj` to load with the wrong component, which won’t fully understand it. This can lead to the sort of errors you reported.
>
> Can you try the following and let us know if it fixes things for you?
>
> - Close Visual Studio.
> - Open your .sln file in a text editor.
> - Replace all occurrences of the `“9A19103F-16F7-4668-BE54-9A1E7A4F7556”` GUID with
>   `“FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC”`
> - Save the .sln file
> - Re-open the solution in Visual Studio.

Comment: As a side note: It is not clear as to why these projects had the wrong GUID. In fact, from my point of perspective, the whole GUID thing is not very well documented, and I would have been very unable to solve this without their support. That's on one side nice, that there is this support to handle the case. On the other side, it would have been even better if I could have figured this out on my own, since it was such a little thing.

Answer (score 0):

This error occurred for me when I was switching between Debug/Release configurations. So I guess it has to do something with configurations then.

Anyway, if I switched to configuration I wanted and then restarted VS, it seems to work fine.

Just for case, someone finds this info helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Removing and re-adding the project fixed it for me.  Must have been a solution file issue.